# write mistake bash_profile

Tags: linux, bash, google-cloud, brew

I am using GCE, I want to install Scala on Google Cloud Shell, so I first install the brew, however when I added the brew path to bash_profile, I did a mistake.

First of All, I downloaded the brew.
Then I wanted to add bew path so I created a bash_profile under the root using vi ~/.bash_profile
Then I wrote the following lines in that file:

```
export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now, I know I need to type **"source ~/.bash_profile"** in prompt not in the bash_profile. But at that time I didn't notice that, and I saved the file, after that, I can no longer open the google cloud shell, it always shows the following infor：
[image]

It said that **Cloud Shell session closed before the initial prompt displayed**, I can only access could shell in safe mode, cannot access the normal could shell using the button [image], does anyone have ideas about how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65144/117549 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/214042/117549

Answer (score 0):

When you make a mistake like this, you need to access Cloud Shell in [safe mode](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features#safe_mode) (as you mention).  When you do so, you will be logged in to Cloud Shell as root and you should be able to edit the .bash_profile file in your regular home directory to remove the offending line:

`vi /home/<your user name>/.bash_profile`